# How to use iterator to iterate a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

all

I am using vector in C++ STL to store my data. I pass and return them into and from functions. However, as the data size grows, the program is slower and slower. Thus I am updating the codes to an "iterator version".

What I want to archieve is that **use iterators to pass, return and iterate STL vectors**.

I am now ok with the operations with 1-dimensional vector, just like manipulating the arrays. However, when it comes to 2-dimensional vector, I am a bit confused.

Can anyone show me **a simple code example that how to iterate a 2D vector using STL iterator**?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Long

Comment: Don't forget you can pass things by const ref to avoid copies. Can you post a code sample of a 2D vector. Is it a vector<vector<int>>?

Comment: -1, your question asks for sample code; sample code for the problem is already available on stackoverflow

Comment: @doctorlove Thank you very much for your replies. Now I figure out the question and get it running properly. However, another question raised: How to get the size of a vector using its iterator?

Comment: Impossible. But why do you need that anyway?

Comment: @doctorlove I use it in order to improve the speed performance of my code. The data chunk I use is usually very big. Thus passing the data variables is very very very time consuming. Thus I though passing the iterator can help me. You've mentioned const reference. May I know what is that idea?

Comment: @user2633803 I've added an answer - I think you need to read a basic book about C++. Try "Accelerated C++"

Answer (score 1):

Well its already somewhere on stackoverflow

But if you don't want to search here it is :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >  vec{ {1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

//Simplest Way:- (C++11)

for(auto row:vec)
{
  for(auto col:row)
   std::cout<<col<< " ";
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}

//OR Using iterator
std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator r;
std::vector<int>::iterator c;
for (r = vec.begin(); r != vec.end(); r++) {
    for (c = r->begin(); c != r->end(); c++) {
        std::cout<<*c<< " ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Can get [distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/) only between two iterators of same container

```
std::vector<int>::iterator s = v2.begin(); //Can be any start
std::vector<int>::iterator e = v2.end(); // Can be any end

std::cout<<"Distance :"<<std::distance(s,e)<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Hi, P0W. I've done iteration 2D vector in another way:`vector<vector<int>>::iterator iter; iter = vec.begin();for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) cout<<iter[i][j]<<' '; cout<<endl; }` sorry about the mess, I am new to this forum and know nothing about the format.

Comment: @user2633803 do not hard code the 3 and 4. Use the iterators

Comment: @doctorlove I've ran a test to see speed difference between iterator and index. It turned out that iterator is not competitive.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong

Comment: @doctorlove "very wrong" for me ? and that is ?

Comment: I am surprised using an iterator is slower than using [] - I suspect there's soemthing else wrong

Answer (score 1):

You state that your basic problem is performance, right?
You assume that this is caused due to copying.
Perhaps there could be simpler solutions for your problem:

- Check if vectors can be passed by (const) reference
- Check if shared_ptr makes sense
- Consider if move semantics can help
- Perhaps compiler version or implementation prevent return value optimization

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to know the size of a vector, and have two iterators `it1` `it2`,

```
std::distance(it1, it2);
```

will tell you the distance between them. This will happen to be the size if they are `begin` and `end`

If you have a function like

```
int work(std::vector<int> items)
{
  //...
}
```

this *copies* the vector items, so will use more RAM and take longer.
Sending a const ref instead will not copy the vector. Making it `const` stops you changing it, which might not help you, but you haven't posted any code so I don't know what you want to do.

```
int work(const std::vector<int> & items)
{
  //...
}
```