# Creating my own Iterators for non stl container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a class that manage data.

I wish to return only a part of the data that is inside it, but since it is a process that will be done multiple times I do not wish to just copy the data inside a container and return the container.

It would be nice if I could just send a reference or something similar. Iterators come to mind. but since I use **Eigen3 Matrix** (which does not have iterators (2D matrix anyway))

I am thinking of *emulating(?)* the iterators behavior,
something like that:

```
typedef unsigned int Index;

class MatrixIterator
{
public:
    MatrixIterator(Eigen::MatrixXd *m, Index min, Index max):
        _col(0), _index(0), _min(min), _max(max), _matrix(m)
    {}

    void operator++ ()   
    {
        if (_index + _min + 1 != _max)
            _index++; 
    }
    void operator--()
    {
        if (_index != _min)
            _index--; 
    }

    double operator*()
    { 
        return _matrix->operator() (_index + _min, _col); 
    }

    void setCol(Index col)  {   _col = col; }

    Index min() {   return _min;    }
    Index max() {   return _max;    }

private:
    // the matrix is 2D we can select
    // on which column we want to iterate
    Index _col;

    // current position
    Index _index;

    // select the range on which the user can iterate
    Index _max;
    Index _min;

    // the matrix on which we want to iterate over
    Eigen::MatrixXd* _matrix;
}
```

- I never really used iterators before, is it correct ?
- Can I inherit my `MatrixIterator` from `std::iterator` so `stl` would be able to understand it as a usual iterator ?
- Do you know a better way to do something similar ?

I have read :

- [Creating my own Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148540/creating-my-own-iterators) - which does not really speak of implementing iterators since they use vector iterator
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/
- [How to use iterator to iterate a 2D vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012618/how-to-use-iterator-to-iterate-a-2d-vector)

EDIT : I want to iterate over only a part of the matrix (that is why I have _min and _max), the data I am manipulating are time series so the data are already ordered.
I think we can consider MatrixIterator as a response to a data query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I never really used iterators before, is it correct ?

It's a good start. The idea is correct, but you are missing a few things. First, you don't have enough operators. Make sure you check the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) and provide every operator that you can sensibly provide (the only ones that may or may not be useful are random-access operators, because it could be harder to implement for this case). Second, you need to provide the [iterator traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator_traits/) for your iterator class. This is usually done by creating the necessary nested typedefs in your iterator class (you could also specialize the `std::iterator_traits` template for your class, but I would say that this is only when you really cannot add the nested typedefs).

> Can I inherit my MatrixIterator from `std::iterator` so stl would be able to understand it as a usual iterator ?

No, you should not, in general, inherit from the `std::iterator` class. The STL is a template library (generic programming (GP)) and therefore, does not use the base-class inheritance model as in OOP. The STL algorithms take iterators as template arguments, and will generically use them as required by the algorithm (or as possible by the `iterator_category` trait associated to the iterator type). This is [generic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming), not object-oriented programming, it's apples and oranges.

> Do you know a better way to do something similar ?

Well, one convenient way to do this is by using a class template like `boost::iterator_facade` (see [ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html)) which provides a sort of automated "fill in the blanks" mechanism creating iterators. It uses the well-known and very useful [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (or CRTP for short). This is useful because implementing all the operators required for iterators can be quite verbose and repetitive, and the usually only really rely on just a few core operations (which is all you need to "fill in" when using a CRTP class like `boost::iterator_facade`).

Comment: +1 for boost::iterator_facade. I've used that one before, and it worked quite nicely. A bit tedious to write, but great to read and use.

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you don't want to tie yourself to the boost library, you can easily reproduce a class similar to `iterator_facace`, just look up the source code for inspiration and reproduce it.